# pauseVideo() on IE8 for youtube videos, gives "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, youtube-javascript-api, object-tag

when trying to use pauseVideo() on IE8 for youtube videos, it gives me "Object doesn't support this property or method",

here is my embedded video:

```
<div class="ytLarge">
    <object width="400" height="300">
        <param value="http://www.youtube.com/v/Y4EZULqhP2E" name="movie">
        <param value="true" name="allowFullScreen">
        <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
        <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
        <embed width="400" height="300" wmode="transparent" 
               allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" 
               type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
               src="http://www.youtube.com/v/Y4EZULqhP2E&autoplay=1&version=3&enablejsapi=1">
    </object>
</div>
```

and here is the calling:

```
$('embed').each(function(index){
        $(this).get(0).pauseVideo();
});
```

the code is working fine in firefox & chrome, but gives the  "Object doesn't support this property or method" on IE8 in the line $(this).get(0).pauseVideo();

Comment: the answer didnt help you ? Let us know

Comment: yes, it didnt' help, cause my concern is how to use .pauseVideo() in IE8, selecting <embed> or even <object> don't help in pausing the video

Answer (score 0):

For what i remind the tag `<embed>` isnt recognize by IE, that's why is used also the tag `<object>` so:

`<object>` is for IE (that's why your script fail in IE)

`<embed>` for all the other browsers

Comment: thanks for that, but how I could use the .pauseVideo() function in IE8, I tried to select the <object> but also didn't work?